# How to run "npm command" run without "run" (i.e. "npm command" instead of "npm run command")?

Tags: node.js, npm

my `package.json` defines:

```
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node scripts/start.js",
        "build": "node scripts/build.js",
        "test": "node scripts/test.js",
        "debug": "node --inspect-brk=9229 scripts/start.js"
    },
    ...
```

Both `npm start` and `npm test` work as `npm run start` and `npm run test` respectively.
However, `npm build` doesn't:

```
$ npm build
npm WARN build `npm build` called with no arguments. Did you mean to `npm run-script build`?
```

I need to put `run` between `npm` and `build`, i.e. `npm run build`.

The same goes for `npm debug`, though the output is different than the output from `npm build`:

```
$ npm debug

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami
```

Of course, it seems to be because `start` and `test` both fall into the `where <command> is one of:` list.

But I was wondering, is there a way to tell `npm` to run an arbitrary `command` like `npm build` or `npm debug` or even `npm my_command` just using just `npm build`/`npm debug`/`npm my_command`?

It's just my curiosity, that's why I am asking.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm so sorry, but it's impossible directly :(

I suppose, **You can** clone the **[npm](https://github.com/npm/cli/tree/latest/lib)** repo **and add your own script**.

And after it You will be able to launch it like `npm my_awesome_command`

Answer (score 4):

You can use yarn instead.
To install yarn globally..(In linux or Mac)

```
sudo npm i -g yarn
```

Then you can try..

```
yarn start
```

See if it works.. 
In my react app it works fine.